# RESTEasy mapping a "legacy" Moodle REST service

Tags: rest, resteasy, moodle

I'm trying to map a "legacy" REST server using RESTEasy client.

The urls of this ws are mapped like this:

http://localhost/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=reallylongtokenhash&wsfunction=core_course_get_courses

The endpoint is always server.php, and the function to call is mapped using a queryparam.

```
@POST
@Path("/server.php")
@Produces("application/json")
List<Map<String, Object>> getCourses(
          @QueryParam("wstoken") String token
        , @QueryParam("wsfunction") String function
        , @QueryParam("moodlewsrestformat") String format);

@POST
@Path("/server.php")
@Produces("application/json")
String createUser(
          @QueryParam("wstoken") String token
        , @QueryParam("wsfunction") String function
        , @QueryParam("moodlewsrestformat") String format
        , @Form User user);
```

which I call in this way

```
private static void getCourses() {
    final MoodleRest client = ProxyFactory.create(MoodleRest.class, "http://localhost/webservice/rest/");
    final List<Map<String, Object>> s = client.getCourses(token, "core_course_get_courses", "json");
    System.out.println("s = " + s);
}
```

Let's ignore the fact that a "get_courses" method is mapped using a POST, and that the token are passed using the QueryParameter on this post, is it possible to avoid passing the function and the response format on every method? I would like to map it using the annotations.

I tried to write in directly into the @Path using

/server.php?function=core_course_get_courses

But obviously this is not the right way to proceed (plus, it doesn't work since it's escaped)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to use HttpServletRequest directly in your method and parse request parameters "by hand". I mean:

```
@POST
@Path("/server.php")
@Produces("application/json")
List<Map<String, Object>> getCourses(@Context HttpServletRequest request){
   //parse request.getParameters()
}
```